# How to restart a "for" loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a question for python coding

I am very new to coding my apologies if my lingo is off or hard to understand

I am trying to learn how to create a multiple question test where the user can only input a string as the input in the for loop, and if they put any other datatype it restarts the for loop ( asks the question again)

Here is what I have

```
class question:

    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer

question_prompt = [

    "what is 2+2? \n a 3 \n b 4 \n c 5 \n d 6 \n input answer here ",
    "what is 3+3? \n a 4 \n b 5 \n c 6 \n d 7 \n input answer here ",
    "what is 10-2?\n a 7 \n b 9 \n c 8 \n d 6 \n input answer here "

]

questions = [

    question(question_prompt[0],"b"),
    question(question_prompt[1],"c"),
    question(question_prompt[2],"c")

]

def run_test(questions):

    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = str(input(question.prompt))
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
       ## if xxxxxxx(): ## This is the line I need help with I want to check if the input is a string and if not print("Wrong input option please enter a letter")


    print("you got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)))

run_test (questions)
```

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: What do you mean by "the user can only input a *string*"? The `input` function always returns a string.

Comment: Without going into the details of the code itself, since you mentioned that your goal is to "restart" the loop, have you considered a while loop instead of a for one? This should make it very easy for you to set the requirements as you need with if statements.

Comment: @Squary94 "have you considered a while loop *instead of a for one*?" The `for` loop is there to iterate through the list of questions and has nothing to do with the OP's wish to retry a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you're trying to do, but your requirement is rather poorly defined. The `input()` function always returns a string as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). So you can't really define your requirement as requiring "some string" as the input. Even if the user inputs what you consider an `int` like `3`, the input function gives you the `str` `"3"`. So you'll need some kind of additional requirements and then check to see if what the user inputed is what you consider a "valid" string. I'll proceed with the rest of the answer assuming you come up with some function that'll validate your string for your requirements

```py
def is_valid(string: str) -> bool:
    """checks if the string is valid"""
    # validation code goes here
```

Considering your question is a multiple choice question and assuming you want the user to input the option corresponding to the answer perhaps your validation code could possibly be

```py
def is_valid(string: str) -> bool:
    valid_options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    return string.lower() in valid_options
```

now to keep looping until the user inputs a valid input you can do something like

```
for question in questions:
    answer = input(question.prompt)
    while not is_valid(answer):
        print("Wrong input, please enter a valid input")
        answer = input(question.prompt)
```

Comment: Since this is multiple choice with answers of a, b, c, or d the validation code could be:  `return string in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'll edit my answer to add that.

Comment: Hi Phoney_badger,
Thank you very much for your help! i sincerely appreciate it.
I was able to get the code running with your help, but there is a part of the code I still do not understand. i tried googling to find the answer first but I couldnt find anything

In the line "def is_valid(input: str) -> bool:" I dont understand the "(input: str)" or the "->" sections of the code.
Can you describe how those are working? is "->" an operator and what does it do? what does the (input : str) do?
My apologies for being so bad ive only been coding for a few days

Comment: Oh I'm sorry since you're a beginner I should've kept it simple and left those out. That is simply a type hint, showing you what the types of the arguments and the return value of the function are. You can leave them out without affecting anything. It is equivalent to `def is_valid(input):`. The `input: str` part simply hints that the input variable is of type string and `-> bool` shows the function returns a boolean. You can learn more about them if you're interested [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). But you can also ignore them for now, they are completely optional.

Comment: oh that makes much more sense! Thank you very much for clarifying and providing me with the link to the type hints, youre a ton of help phoney_badger! I appreciate you beyond belief.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use **isinstance(variable, str)**  returns boolean value.

```
if isinstance(question, str) != True:
        print("Wrong input option please enter a letter")
```